What does the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian tell us about quantum systems
I can grasp the mathematics of the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian on the macro scale - like the typical pendulum.  But I can't understand what they tell us at the quantum scale.  What do they tell us about the equations of motion of a quark or a gluon and how that has an impact on associated systems? How do we bring them into a quantum theory?  An example of using them in a quantum theory, with an explanation, would be helpful.  For example, could we use them to explain how electron spin in a bar magnet leads to the surrounding magnetic field?

There are already questions and answers here about that; you don't need the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian to get that result. The electron has spin angular momentum because it's a fermion, which results in a magnetic moment.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


How do we bring them into a quantum theory?

The path integral approach to quantum mechanics is the most straightforward way that I know of to connect the classical expression for the lagrangian to quantum theory.
In the quantum theory, each path is weighed by the exponential of the action:
$$
e^{iS/\hbar}\;,
$$
where
$$
S=S[x]=\int dt L(x,\dot x)\;,
$$
and where $x$ is the path and L is the Lagrangian.
E.g., for a simple harmonic oscillator:
$$
L(x, v) = \frac{1}{2}m v^2 - \frac{1}{2}k x^2
$$
